# Update more than one nodes with the same label at the same time in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

How can i update these three nodes with the same label at the same time in neo4j.I tried the following but it will not work.

**Method 1:**

```
START n=node(0) 
MATCH n-[r:HAS_GRADE]->(g:Grade)-[r1:HAS_SYLLABUS]->(sy:Syllabus)
OPTIONAL MATCH (sy)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(s:Subject) SET s:Publish WITH s
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(c:Chapter) SET c:Publish WITH c
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(t:Topic) SET t:Publish 
RETURN s;
```

**Method 2**

```
    START n=node(0) 
    MATCH n-[r:HAS_GRADE]->(g:Grade)-[r1:HAS_SYLLABUS]->(sy:Syllabus)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (sy)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(s:Subject)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(c:Chapter)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(t:Topic) WITH s,c,t
    SET s:Publish  
    SET c:Publish
    SET t:Publish
    RETURN s;
```

**Method 3**

```
START n=node(0) 
MATCH n-[r:HAS_GRADE]->(g:Grade)-[r1:HAS_SYLLABUS]->(sy:Syllabus)
OPTIONAL MATCH (sy)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(s:Subject)
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(c:Chapter)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:HAS_CHILD]->(t:Topic) WITH s,c,t
SET s:Publish, c:Publish, t:Publish
RETURN s
```

Do i need to run this query 3 times to update the three nodes. Or is there any alternate methods? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
START n=node(0) 
MATCH n-[r:HAS_GRADE]->(g:Grade)-[r1:HAS_SYLLABUS]->(sy:Syllabus)-[:HAS_CHILD*]->(c)
WHERE any(x in labels(c) WHERE x in ["Subject","Chapter","Topic"])
SET c :Publish
RETURN c
```

The `WHERE` makes sure that the end nodes of the `HAS_CHILD` carries one the labels given in the list.

We're using a variable path length (see the `*`) with `HAS_CHILD` to grab all the children nodes.

Comment: ah, didn't read your statements correctly. gonna update my answer.

Comment: Yup... Now it it is working properly.. Nice.. Thank You.. :)